# Hibernate MSSQL nvarchar Equivalent datatype in oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, hibernate-mapping

We are developed project using hibernate with sql server. Now we are migrating sql server to oracle. 
We have user Nvarchar datatype in mssql server for more than 80 tables. While we are trying to create tables in oracle through hibernate table containing Nvarchar datatype are not getting generated other table are creating successfully.

While we change the column to varchar than also table are getting generated.

How to create UTF-8 datatype in oracle and mssql as a common datatype in hibernate.

Please Help !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What is your database character set?  Assuming that you create the database setting the database character set to AL32UTF8, `VARCHAR2` columns in Oracle would store data in the UTF-8 character set.

If you cannot use a Unicode character set for your database character set, you'd need to use `nvarchar2` columns.  An `nvarchar2` column stores data using the national character set.  Unless you've upgraded from an old version of Oracle, your database character set would use the UTF-16 character set, not UTF-8.